# waitForTransform fails in Callback

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to get the transform from "/world" to "/velodyne" so that I can obtain the point cloud in the world frame. The code is as follows:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <tf_conversions/tf_eigen.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>

void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& cloud_msg_in){
    tf::TransformListener tf_listener_;
    if(tf_listener_.waitForTransform("world", "velodyne", cloud_msg_in.header.stamp, ros::Duration(10.0))){
        std::cout<<"[tf is obtained]"<<std::endl;
        tf::StampedTransform tf_transform;
        tf_listener_.lookupTransform("world", "velodyne", cloud_msg_in.header.stamp, tf_transform);
    }else{
        std::cout<<"[wait for tf failed]"<<std::endl;;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_test_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber scan_sub = nh.subscribe("/velodyne_points", 1u, &scanCallback);
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

Then, I played a rosbag, but the output of this node was always "[wait for tf failed]". I tried to change "world" to "/world" and "velodyne" to "/velodyne", but it didnot work. I also run `rosrun tf tf_echo \world \velodyne`, and the output is correct. And the tf_tree of the rosbag is also correct. Moreover, the output of `rostopic echo \tf` was correct. I have no idea why the code cannot get the \tf, any advises will be appreciated.(The robag can be download from [link text](http://robotics.ethz.ch/%7Easl-datasets/segmap/segmap_data/kitti/2011_10_03_drive_27.bag))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318641/waitfortransform-fails-in-callback/) by [leon J.](https://answers.ros.org/users/40483/leon-j./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`TransformListener` needs some time to fill its buffer. You don't give it any time, as you construct it in the callback itself.

Create it in `main(..)` and make sure `scanCallback(..)` can access it to call `lookupTransform(..)` on it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leon J.](https://answers.ros.org/users/40483/leon-j./) on 2019-03-18**:
Thank you for answering, it really works.